# Reporting Kruskal-Wallis Test Result with Pairwise Comparisons

Tags: spss, kruskal-wallis-test, reporting

I have run a Kruskal Wallis Test on my data and it is significant at p=0.00. I have currently reported the output as H (3) = 18.047, p<0.00. However, I now need to see where the difference between my groups lies, so ran pairwise comparisons. Here, looking at the adjusted significance there is a statistically significant difference between two pairs of groups (one at p=0.001 and the other p= 0.002)

My question is how do I incorporate these values into what I've already written. Is it a case of writing pairwise comparisons were conducted and then reporting the adjusted significance for each? And do I keep the original overall Kruskal Wallis significance?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, keep the overall test and then write that you conducted pairwise tests. I would do something like this (but I'd change the writing to relate it more to the data)

"A Kruskal-Wallis test showed that at there was a significant difference of means (H = 18.047, p <0.001). I then conducted post hoc tests to test pairwise comparisons. I found that group A was significantly different to group B (p = 0.001) and group C (p = 0.002). Groups B and C were not significantly different (p = 0.23)."

That would be my 'template answer'. I'd alter it to fit your data.

Comment: Thank you so much for a quick response - very much appreciated!

Comment: No worries. If it answered your question feel free to mark this question as answered